# CherryPy redirect to root on missing parameters error

Tags: python, redirect, error-handling, cherrypy

I have a web server using CherryPy. I would like for users to be redirected to the root page if they try and access a page which requires parameters to be entered. If a user were to try and directly access:

```
localhost:8080/page
```

they will get an error message which looks something like:

> **404 Not Found**
>
> Missing parameters: parameter1,parameter2,...

Instead of this, I would like the user to be redirected to:

```
localhost:8080/
```

I have tried to change cherrypy.config such that whenever a 404 occurs, it checks the error message and sees if the issue is missing parameters. If this is not the issue, I would like the default 404 page to be shown. My code looks like this:

```
cherrypy.config.update({'error_page.404': error_page_404})
```

with the function error_page_404:

```
def error_page_404(status, message, traceback, version):
    if message.startswith('Missing parameters'):
        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect('/')
    else:
        raise cherrypy.HTTPError(status, message)
```

but when I try to access

```
localhost:8080/page,
```

I get the following error:

> **404 Not Found**
>
> Missing parameters: parameter1,parameter2
>
> In addition, the custom error page failed:
>
> cherrypy._cperror.HTTPRedirect: (['http://127.0.0.1:8080/'], 303)

Any thoughts?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make a workaround by returning HTML code that redirects to the root:

```py
def error_page_404(status, message, traceback, version):
    if message.startswith('Missing parameters'):
        return """<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='/'" />"""
    else:
        return f'<h2>404 Not Found</h2>\n' \
               f'<p>{message}</p>'
```

While this works for my purposes, I can't help but feel there must be a more native way of doing this in cherrypy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).